# Enum not iterable in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

```
from enum import Enum

class Shake(Enum):
    __order__ = 'vanilla chocolate cookies mint' # only needed in 2.x
    vanilla = 7
    chocolate = 4
    cookies = 9
    mint = 3

for shake in Shake:
    print shake
```

Getting error while running this code

```
  for shake in Shake:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Is iteration not supported for `Enum` in Python 2.7? It works if we make a object of the `Enum` type.

Comment: Given that you're having trouble with an example right out of [the documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34/), you should really raise this as an issue with the developers. They will probably want more information, though - exactly what version (of `enum` and Python) are you using, how did you install `enum`, etc. Have you checked that you *are* using their library (i.e. not some other `enum.py` that shadows it - try `print enum.__file__`)?

Comment: `enum` module is not included in Python 2.7. Which `enum` module did you install?

Comment: i installed pip install Enum which causes issue, pip install enum34 solves it

Answer (score 11):

The backport of the Python 3.4 Enum type is [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), not [enum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum).

Comment: Wow you are the developer! :)