# Iterating Enums in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, enums, ironpython

I'm working with IronPython 2.7.9, and have installed `enums` with pip (`ipy -X:Frames -m pip install --user enum`). So I expect [enums to work](https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/enum.html).

To some extent, they do:

```
S:\>ipy
IronPython 2.7.9 (2.7.9.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (64-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from enum import Enum
>>>
>>> class Shake(Enum):
...     vanilla = 7
...     chocolate = 4
...     cookies = 9
...     mint = 3
...
>>> Shake.vanilla
7
```

… but not when I try to iterate through their values:

```
>>> for shake in Shake:
...     print shake
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected Array[Type], got int
```

Am I misunderstanding something? Are Python enums just not compatible with IronPython?

As an alternative, I'm open to using .Net's enumerations, but [the documentation is entirely rudimentary](https://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#enumerations). Can anybody point to comprehensive docs about enumerations in IronPython?

Comment: I added the duplicate tag because the corresponding question/answer is about the backport of the stdlib's `Enum`.  Since `Enum`, `enum34`, and `aenum` are all pure Python code they *should* work on any Python.

Comment: Point taken on IronPython, so I'll remove that from the title. But this question is about an error message, and the other question is about which library is current. If they're duplicate questions, then a question about the colour of a clear sky and a question about the colour of a Little Kingfisher are duplicates too.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't the best duplicate question.  ;-)  This one should be better.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29770225/208880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enum` package does not correspond to that API. You need the Python 3 backport, [`enum34`](https://pypi.org/project/enum34/).

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I was mislead by 'Source code: Lib/enum.py' in the docs. Do you know of a reliable way to tell from the docs which package to use? It is rather odd to see 'New in version 3.4' in the 2.7.6 documentation!

Comment: @MichaelScheper: Unfortunately there were already several enum packages in existence when it was finally added in 3.4, so I chose the name `enum34`.  I strongly recommend my [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) package, though, as it benefits from continued development, and is 2.7/3.3+ compatible.